# Better than Casella and Berger's *Statistical Inference*?

Tags: statistics, reference-request

I have just finished an undergraduate degree in statistics and am looking into a graduate degree in statistics.

One textbook that I've found in my searching is Casella and Berger's *Statistical Inference* (which is supposed to cover the theory of probability and statistics); however, I've found that many have stated that it lacks clarity.

Is there a "better" reference for this topic?

Note: I used Wackerly et al.'s *Mathematical Statistics with Applications* when I was an undergraduate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best choice might depend on which type of book you would prefer. In my opinion:

- If you want to privilege clarity, I would suggest you "Models for Probability and Statistical Inference: Theory and Applications" by James H. Stapleton: this is a relatively short but clear and comprehensive book on probability and statistical inference, with a lot of images and simulations that can be very useful;
- If you are interested in completeness, I would suggest you "Probability and Statistical Inference"  by Robert V. Hogg: this is a classical "milestone" book on this topic, a very comprehensive course that in its last edition is enriched by a CD with several data sets formatted for most statistical software packages;
- If you are interested in a "mathematical" approach, an appropriate choice could be "Mathematical Statistics, Basic Ideas and Selected Topics" by Peter J. Bickel: this is a high-level book written from a strictly mathematical  standpoint, containing good sections also on inference and probability theory;
- If you search something midway between simplicity and completeness, maybe a good text could be "Introduction to Probability Theory and Statistical Inference" by Harold J. Larson: despite relatively older, in my opinion this remains a very clear statistical course.

I hope that these advices could be helpful to you.

Comment: do you think that Hogg is better than Casella and Berger ?

Comment: In my opinion Hogg is clear and complete.

Comment: yeah but is Casella worse ? because some chapters are better written for me in Casella